# How do I get OneDrive back once I've uninstalled it?

Tags: onedrive

I was super-annoyed with Microsoft pushing OneDrive on me, so I uninstalled it, and even did the registry hacks to remove the icon from file explorer and the system tray.

And then I got a job at a company that uses OneDrive for everything. Whoops.

Now I can't get it back.

I have reinstalled it, and it shows in the programs menu, but when I try to run it, nothing happens. I get a short hourglass, then it goes away, and nothing else happens. I assume a process starts then stops for whatever reason.

And the icon is not in file explorer anymore, so I have nowhere I can "go" to try and explore it.

I can only assume my registry hacking is not something easily "un-doable."  (And, no, I don't remember what I did, exactly.)

How do I get this back?

(Also, there's no SU tag for "schadenfreude," which clearly applies here...)

Comment: It is possible to screw up the app with registry changes.  Try two things:   (1) in an Admin Command prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW. Restart when done and try installing again.  (2) Make a new, test Windows User Account, log into the new Windows account and try One Drive there.

Comment: If all else fails, re-install over the top of the existing installation, selecting the option to preserve current programs, settings and user data (but back up fully first - don't trust the installer not to lose data). Afterwards you will need to repeat some of the customisation changes you previously made. If this doesn't work, you will need to start from scratch with a clean install, unless you have a back-up from before the time you removed OD.

Comment: What version of Windows 10?  What registry hacks specifically?

Comment: If you want to postpone the Full Clean Installation Procedure a little bit, then you can visit [this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odfiles-sdwin10/troubleshooting-a-synchronization/c341841b-8be3-4936-9a3c-47689aa90176?page=1) and read there a conversation that I have once endured with some members of the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ _OneDrive_ Support Teams. It gives you most of the clues that one might apply in order to revive it.